# Gravity Forms create feeds on subsite creation

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, feed, multisite

I'm trying to import a coulple of forms with feeds on the subsite creation. I exported the feeds and pasted the sql in the code, but when try to execute it, I got "no such table exist" error. The table definitely exists, but I think it's just not created when hook triggers. I've included gravityforms feed addon  and made in init. Didn't help;

```
 <?php

add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'add_forms', 10, 6); // trigger when site is created

function add_forms($blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta) {

    switch_to_blog($blog_id);


    import_forms_on_loaded('/forms/primary-forms.json'); //import 1st forms set
    import_primary_feeds(); //import the feeds

    $import_additional = true; //some bool to define whether additional forms be created

    if ($import_additional) {
        import_forms_on_loaded('/forms/additional-forms.json'); //import 2nd forms set
        import_additional_feeds(); //import the feeds
    }


    restore_current_blog();
}

function import_primary_feeds() {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO %s (id, form_id, is_active, feed_order, meta, addon_slug) VALUES " .
            "(1, 1, 1, 0, '{\"feedName\":\"PayDock Donate Create Customer Feed\",\"mappedFields_first_name\":\"7.3\",\"mappedFields_last_name\":\"7.6\",\"mappedFields_email\":\"1\",\"mappedFields_phone\":\"8\",\"mappedFields_total\":\"19\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic\":\"0\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic_object\":[]}', 'gfpaydock')," .
            "(2, 2, 1, 0, '{\"feedName\":\"PayDock Donate Charge Customer Feed \",\"paymentDescription\":\"Single Payment\",\"transactionType\":\"product\",\"paymentAmount\":\"3\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic\":\"0\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic_object\":[]}', 'gfpaydockchargecustomer')," .
            "(3, 3, 1, 0, '{\"feedName\":\"PayDock Donate Recurrent Charge Customer Feed\",\"paymentDescription\":\"Recurrent Payment\",\"transactionType\":\"subscription\",\"recurringAmount\":\"3\",\"billingCycle_length\":\"1\",\"billingCycle_unit\":\"month\",\"transaction_end\":\"\",\"transaction_end_value\":\"\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic\":\"0\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic_object\":[]}', 'gfpaydockchargecustomer');";
    import_feeds($sql);
}

function import_additional_feeds() {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO %s (id, form_id, is_active, feed_order, meta, addon_slug) VALUES " .
            "(4, 5, 1, 0, '{\"feedName\":\"PayDock Membership Create Customer Feed \",\"mappedFields_first_name\":\"5.3\",\"mappedFields_last_name\":\"5.6\",\"mappedFields_email\":\"8\",\"mappedFields_phone\":\"7\",\"mappedFields_total\":\"37\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic\":\"0\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic_object\":[]}', 'gfpaydock')," .
            "(5, 6, 1, 0, '{\"feedName\":\"PayDock Membership Charge Customer Feed\",\"paymentDescription\":\"Membership Payment\",\"transactionType\":\"subscription\",\"recurringAmount\":\"3\",\"billingCycle_length\":\"1\",\"billingCycle_unit\":\"year\",\"transaction_end\":\"\",\"transaction_end_value\":\"\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic\":\"0\",\"feed_condition_conditional_logic_object\":[]}', 'gfpaydockchargecustomer');";

    import_feeds($sql);
}

function import_feeds($sql) {
    if (!class_exists('GFForms')) {
        return;
    }
    GFForms::init();
    GFForms::include_feed_addon_framework();

    if (!class_exists('GFFeedAddOn')) {
        return;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $feed_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'gf_addon_feed';

    $result = $wpdb->get_results(sprintf($sql, $feed_table));
    return $result;
}

?>
```

I didn't use the form creating constant, as I neded deveral files to import.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. To force tables creation, you have to create your own empty addon object by extending the GFFeedAddOn and call the parent's init-method:

Somewhere in the global code:

```
class EmptyAddon extends GFFeedAddOn { //an empty class required to import the GF Feeds

        function __construct() {
            parent::init();
        }

    }
```

In the function that initiates the addons functionality:

```
if (!class_exists('GFForms')) {
    return;
}

GFForms::init();
GFForms::include_feed_addon_framework();

if (!class_exists('GFFeedAddOn')) {
    return;
}

$emptyAddonObj = new EmptyAddon();
```